# Проблема с require_once, ломает верстку

Tags: php

Пытаюсь писать код в стиле MVC через точку входа. И как только добавляю require_once - ломается вёрстка, подскажите в чем проблема?

**Точка входа**

```
<?php

//запрет прямого обращения
define('VVV',true);

//подключение фаила конфигурации
require_once 'config.php';

//подключения контроллера
require_once CONTROLLER;

?>
```

**Контроллер**

```
<?php

//проверка запрета прямого обращения
defined('VVV') or die('Access denied');

echo Контроллер;

// подключение модели (выводится надпись "Модель")
require_once MODEL;

//подключение вида (находится в каталоге)
require_once VIEW.'index.php';

?>
```

В итоге в браузере ломается верстка

```
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>КонтроллерМодель
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </body>
</html>
```

"DOCTYPE" попросту исчез, а содержимое хедера "падает" все в body
Проверял кодировку, везде utf-8

Помогите пожалуйста, уже целый день голову ломаю, с таким в первый раз столкнулся...

Comment: А можно код самого view . Хотябы короткий вариант.

Comment: Сразу первое замечание, избавьтесь от закрывающих PHP тэгов `?>`

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте `require_once VIEW.'index.php';` выше по коду. Перед `echo Контроллер;`
Вобще, вывод информации (echo), должен происходить в view-шке, а не в контроллере. Контроллер должен только передавать необходимую информацию в файл представления.

Answer (score -2):

Надо было вывод надписи "контроллер" и "модуль" убрать в контроллере и модуле.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?